# How to update a mongodb/mongoose schema from a single value field to a multi value field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a schema defined in Mongoose like this:

```
var Stuff = new Schema({
    href:           String,
    thing:          Number,
});
```

But now the "thing" field is more complicated than a single number, so I'd like to update my model make "thing" have embedded fields:

```
var Stuff = new Schema({
    href:           String,
    thing:          { thinglabel: String, 
                      thingvalue: Number}
});
```

I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to do this. For the time being, I've hacked around this problem by adding a second field but I was thinking that there might be a better solution the next time I run into this problem.

Comment: Stop your site, upgrade all documents, start the site with new schema. This is the easiest way.

Comment: Step 1: stop site
Step 2: in Mongo console write a script to update all the documents
Step 3: update Mongoose schema to the updated schema
Step 4: start the design

Yeah, this will work, but I was hopping for something classier :-)

Thanks for the help.